# PySAL, ValueError: cannot assign slice from input of different size

Tags: python, geopandas, moran-index, pysal

I want to calculate local moran's I statistics using `pysal` with `Queen` contiguity but I'm getting error.

```
import geopandas as gpd             
from pysal.explore import esda  
from pysal.lib import weights
gdf = gpd.read_file("\\CA_Places\\CA_Places_TIGER2016.shp")
w_queen = weights.Queen.from_dataframe(gdf)
lisa = esda.moran.Moran_Local(gdf['ALAND'], w_queen)

# ValueError: cannot assign slice from input of different size
```

I have shown here with [EXAMPLE Dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Esr0gFElpD1mWH3sIcPl0oJjVsUnXBCP?usp=sharing) but actually I'm getting error with my original dataset also.
I did some research and couldn't find anything related to the problem. `Moran_Local` is working fine with other weights like `KNN` for my dataset but with `Queen`, it fails.

Comment: That dataset has 1522 regions and 616 of them aren't connected to any other regions by this adjacency. That will make computing Moran's I... tricky.

Comment: @Spacedman If we use `KNN` weights then Moran's I can be calculated for this same dataset. I'm thinking that maybe it is not possible to calculate Moran's I for the datasets with islands using `Queen` or Rook` weights.

Comment: Yes, a region will always have some nearest neighbours. In R's spdep package, you can force it to compute a Moran test with disconnected regions, but you have to tell the function to use zeros. I get a Moran I of 0.11637 for your ALAND data, with a variance of 0.00058, so definitely not zero and showing positive spatial autocorrelation. I don't know if PySAL's Moran code can do this... Anything in the docs?

Comment: @Spacedman Islands and disconnected regions are two different things in `PySAL`. I computed Global Moran's I with queen contiguity.  But in case of Local Moran's I, PySAL is not allowing weights with islands but disconnected components are fine here. Anyways I calculated weights for my dataset by using Kernel weights with adaptive distance like `weights.distance.Kernel.from_dataframe(gdf, fixed=False, k=15)` and that worked fine. But for weights with islands like `Queen`, PySAL's Local Moran I is not working and In documentation, no instructed for not using queen or rook weights.